# Batch Query Based on Custom Setting

Tags: batch

I have a batch class that runs on all leads unless the user has entered a specific lead Record Type into a custom setting field. I'm getting an "System.QueryException: Invalid alias" even though when I have tested out the query in the query editor and it works fine. Below is the code for the base batch query and the expanded one if they have entered a lead type.

```
    batchquery = 'SELECT Name, Email, id, Compete__CompeteURL__c, Compete__CompeteUVs__c, Compete__CompeteVisits__c, Compete__CompeteLastUpdated__c FROM lead';
    if(setup.Lead_Record_Type__c != null){
      batchquery += 'WHERE RecordType.Name = \'' + setup.Compete__Lead_Record_Type__c + '\'';
      }else{}
```

Where is the invalid alias error coming from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing space in string formation.

`batchquery += ' WHERE RecordType.Name = \'' + setup.Compete__Lead_Record_Type__c + '\'';`